# What is the use of the hyphen before a function in SQL (SQLServer)

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, unary-function

I would like to find out what the logic behind the SQL Syntax is when including a hyphen before calling a SQL function enclosed in parentheses.

Here is the SQL:

```
IF (@StartDate > @EndDate)
BEGIN
    SET @EndDate = @StartDate
    SET @StartDate = @EndDate
END

DECLARE @nonworkingweekdays int

--now deal with public holidays
SELECT @nonworkingweekdays = count("Date") from 
(
    select distinct
    (
    CASE datepart(weekday,date)
            WHEN 1 THEN null --ignore sundays   
            WHEN 7 THEN null --ignore saturdays
            else "Date"
    END
    ) AS "date" 
    from publicholidays
) nonworkingweekdays 
WHERE 
"Date" is not null and 
"Date" between @StartDate and DATEADD(day, -1, @EndDate)

RETURN
    CASE WHEN @StartDate <= @EndDate
    THEN
        dbo.FullWeekDays(@StartDate, @EndDate) - @nonworkingweekdays
    ELSE
        -(dbo.FullWeekDays(@StartDate, @EndDate) - @nonworkingweekdays)
    END
```

The logic I am confused about is in the **else** statement with the **return** statement at the bottom of this script.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's the same as multiplying with -1, look at the CASE condition that is probably the reason why a negative value is returned

Comment: Minus, to negate a value.

Comment: The - is not in front of the function call actually...and it's outside the bracket too. So the - is applied to the _result_ of the function minus the value of @nonworkingweekdays (I.e the result of the calculation inside the brackets). So assuming the function returns a number, then the - will simply negate it. E.g. if the operation in the brackets returns 4 then the final result output by the else condition will be -4.

Comment: BTW, `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. Simply do `select distinct CASE datepart(weekday,date) ...` to make code clearer!

Comment: It means someone isn't paying attention to their code since a) they could just use [`ABS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/abs-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) even if it were necessary, which it isn't since b) The logic at the top means that the `ELSE` clause is never considered.

Comment: and c) the logic at the top has never been tested since it doesn't *swap* the values of the two variables, it just ends up with both set to whatever value `@StartDate` has before this code runs.

Comment: Note the [`ABS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/functions/abs-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) inbuilt function which avoids branching in cases like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the TSQL [Unary Negative Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/unary-operators-negative?view=sql-server-2017):

> Returns the negative of the value of a numeric expression (a unary
>   operator). Unary operators perform an operation on only one expression
>   of any one of the data types of the numeric data type category.

Answer (score 1):

It is a unary negation operator, so the same as `(0 - <expression>)`.

That said, I am guessing that this is more simply expressed as:

```
RETURN ABS(dbo.FullWeekDays(@StartDate, @EndDate) - @nonworkingweekdays)
```

Comment: But as I noted in the comments, look at the logic at the top of the code. `ELSE` was unused anyway...

Answer (score 0):

The hyphen is there to reverse the sign of the expression's value, because in the case you have there:

```
CASE WHEN @StartDate <= @EndDate
THEN
    dbo.FullWeekDays(@StartDate, @EndDate) - @nonworkingweekdays
ELSE
    -(dbo.FullWeekDays(@StartDate, @EndDate) - @nonworkingweekdays)
END
```

you are returning the difference between the dates minus the `nonworkingdays` variable.

it is logically the best option, because you cant have a -1 days difference, you always need a positive integerin the difference.

be sure to make a way to differentiate between the types of return (when the `startdate` is greater than `enddate` and vice-versa)